# Why does the newest OS Monterey ask always permission for Mic when using i.e. MobilVOIP?

Tags: permission, microphone

It is annoying. I gave permission for the app to access the microphone, but macOS ask always for permission when I run it.

[image]

Comment: Is the app coded to always ask for permission even if permission was already given?

Comment: I do not know, I do not think so. How can I check it?

Comment: Install it on a non-monterey Mac or ask the developer.  The only reason I can think of why this specific app would keep popping up the prompt is it's not checking the permissions properly.

Comment: Maybe I should reinstall?